# How can I make a regular expression that only matches the middle bracket of nested brackets?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make a regular expression that will only match the middle bracket if there are nested brackets. For instance, if you type in x(x+3(x+3)) I would want it to only match the (x+3). I have several regular expressions in my program already which involve brackets, and I have discovered they always match the first instance of brackets that they find. In the example above, my regular expressions match (x+3(x+3), and I guess that should have been obvious but I didn't think about it when I started. Essentially, I want it to match a set of brackets that does not contain a '(' or a ')' character inside the bracket.

Here is my regular expression for a single bracket: re.compile(r'(\S+?)').
I would use some sort of negative lookaround, but I think that would prevent the necessary open and close bracket characters at the beginning and end respectively...

I am using Python. Also when I say 'brackets' I mean parentheses, but in British English we say brackets :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe something like `\(.*((\.*\)).*\)`, using a capturing group? This very well may not be a regular grammar. You might have to specify a Context Free Grammar instead.

Comment: this `(\([^()]+\))`?  should work .. see https://regexr.com/3nsfg

Comment: @PatrickArtner `[^()]` I think ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to capture something that does not entail some other things is with

`[^ ....]` - the ^ disallowes anything inside the [] - as a special feature you do not need to escape brackets inside it - so by declaring your regex as

```
r'(\([^()]+\))'
```

you essentially capture a literal `(` followed bei 1+ anythings but neither `(` nor `)` followed by a literal `)`.

See  https://regexr.com/3nsfg

From  [Regex Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> - Characters that are not within a range can be matched by complementing the set. If the first character of the set is `^`, all
>     the characters that are not in the set will be matched. For example,
>     `[^5]` will match any character except '5', and `[^^]` will match any
>     character except '^'. ^ has no special meaning if it’s not the first
>     character in the set.
> - To match a literal ']' inside a set, precede it with a backslash, or place it at the beginning of the set. For example, both `[()[\]{}]`
>     and `[]()[{}]` will both match a parenthesis.

Code:

```
t = "x(x+3(x+3))"

import re

m = re.findall(r"(\([^()]+\))", t)

print(m[0])
```

Output:

```
(x+3)
```